# Characteristic Subgroup Definition - $T(C)\subseteq C$ or $T(C)=C$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Herstein Topics in Algebra a subgroup $C$ of $G$ is a characteristic subgroup if $T(C)\subseteq C$ for all automorphisms $T$ of $G$.

In Gallian Contemporary Algebra a subgroup $C$ of $G$ is a characteristic subgroup if $T(C)=C$ for all automorphisms $T$ of $G$.

My instructor said Herstein uses a more concise definition although the two conditions are equivalent. I am not sure I fully understand why this is the case. I know that an automorphism is a homomorphism from $G$ to $G$ that is one-to-one and onto, but I cannot seem to figure out why $C\subseteq T(C)$ as well.

Can anyone clear this up for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Note that it is also assumed that $T^{-1}(C)\subseteq C$.

Comment: Haha ... perfect! Thank you for the quick and easy explanation!